# Migrate existing table data to new table and change the column value based on result of query to other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, sql-update

So I have 2 identical tables table1 and table2. I want to migrate data from table1 to table2.

I can use this query:-

```
insert into table2(table2_id, definition_string, description, active) 
select nextval('table2_id_seq'), definition_string, description, active from table1;
```

But there is some more change to do in column `definition_string`.

The column `definition_string` of new table `table2` should now have emails  replaced with usernames which were in `table1`.

**For example-**

**table1**

> definition_string =

```
SEND open TO abc@gmail.com
SEND close TO abc@gmail.com
SEND open TO def@gmail.com ghi@gmail.com
SEND close TO def@gmail.com ghi@gmail.com
SEND open TO jkl@gmail.com
SEND close TO jkl@gmail.com
```

The above definition_string should be replaced to-

**table2**

> definition_string =

```
SEND open TO usera
SEND close TO usera
SEND open TO userb userc
SEND close TO userb userc
SEND open TO userd
SEND close TO userd
```

The replacement of email to username should be based on lookup at table `user`-

```
select username from user where email = 'abc@gmail.com';
```

**RESULT:**

> username=

```
usera
userx
usery
```

The above query may result in one or more usernames. If the query results in more than one usernames then we will only consider the first one for the replacement.

Although not correct but I tried this-

```
update 
  table2 
set 
  definition_string = case when definition_string = 'SEND open TO abc@gmail.com' then (
    select 
      username 
    from 
      user 
    where 
      email = 'abc@gmail.com'
  ) when definition_string = 'SEND close TO def@gmail.com ghi@gmail.com' then (
    select 
      username 
    from 
      user 
    where 
      email = 'def@gmail.com' || 'ghi@gmail.com'
  ) else definition_string -- don't change anything
  end;
```

I was thinking to write a for loop which iterates through all of the rows of `table1`. But seems like it is not efficient to loop over?

Comment: How many records are in the tables?  I see a way to do it, but if there are tens of millions of rows, it would not be a good approach.

Comment: @Hambone- I do not have tens of millions of rows.I only have 2000 rows. So please let me know the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ordinarily would shy away from procedural loops, but the problem doesn't lend itself well to a pure SQL solution (not that I can see, at least), so I think a loop is the way to go.  Here is an example of how you would just do the translation from table1 to table2, with the conversion in place:

```
create or replace function update_table() returns void as $$
declare
  rw table2%rowtype;
  prefix text;
  emails text;
  emaili text;
  user_id text;
begin
  for rw in select * from table1
  loop
    prefix := substring (rw.definition_string from '(SEND \w+ TO) ');
    emails := substring (rw.definition_string from 'SEND \w+ TO (.+)');

    foreach emaili in array string_to_array (emails, ' ')
    loop
      select username
      into user_id
      from users where email = emaili;

      prefix := prefix || ' ' || user_id;
    end loop;

    insert into table2 values
    (nextval ('table2_id_seq'), prefix);
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Alternatively you could use the same concept and compartmentalize the translation in a function:

```
create or replace function email_to_user(email_address text) returns text as $$
declare
  prefix text;
  emails text;
  emaili text;
  user_id text;
begin
  prefix := substring (email_address from '(SEND \w+ TO) ');
  emails := substring (email_address from 'SEND \w+ TO (.+)');

  foreach emaili in array string_to_array (emails, ' ')
  loop
    select username
    into user_id
    from users where email = emaili;

    prefix := prefix || ' ' || user_id;
  end loop;

  return prefix;
end;
$$
  language plpgsql;
```

Simple proof of concept:

```
select id, definition_string, email_to_user(definition_string) from table1
```

Or:

```
insert into table2(table2_id, definition_string, description, active) 
select
  nextval('table2_id_seq'), email_to_user (definition_string), description, active 
from table1;
```

Or, if you really want to update existing records, regardless of how they got there:

```
update table2
set definition_string = email_to_user (definition_string)
where definition_string != email_to_user (definition_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the query `select id, definition_string, email_to_user(definition_string) from table1` is giving null values for `email_to_user` function.

Comment: I think it is not getting email substrings from `emails := substring (email_address from 'SEND \w+ TO (.+)')`. This is getting the whole `definition_string` column value.

Comment: Yeah, if it doesn't meet that regex pattern it would return null.  Can you enumerate all possibilities for the string prefix (prior to the emails)?

Comment: Ok. You gave me hint that problem is in regex. I found some words before `SEND \w+ TO`.  So I used `.* SEND \w+ TO` in regex and it worked. In some cases if we have resulting multiple usernames …then Is it possible to change the `email_to_user` function to map to any user ? For ex. - if `abc@gmail.com` results in `usera` and `userb` and I want `userb` for this email then can we map it in that function itself?

Comment: I got it with `if else` conditions within loop. For ex. - `if emaili is 'abc@gmail.com' then prefix := prefix || ' ' || 'userb'; else prefix := prefix || ' ' || user_id;`

Comment: I was going to suggest you include an `order by` in the select but specify how you wanted to pick the email when there were multiple...  for example, if it was based on the most recent one `order by create_date desc`.

Comment: Oh I am understanding what you are saying. However, it is not based on most recent one. It is a choice of the team to decide which one to pick if its multiple so `if else` will work. One more thing - Is this a cursor that you wrote ? I heard somewhere that cursor works faster in looping through rows.

Comment: This is not a cursor.  If you are using the first version (where the function does the update), then there are some potential improvements you could make.  If you are using the "email_to_user" function, then I don't think it would improve anything.  For 2,000 records, if the user table is indexed, I doubt you will run into any major performance issues.  If this goes to millions, then I would rethink the entire problem.

Comment: I have another question for the same.. please check here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942157/simple-way-to-read-an-email-to-username-mapping-and-if-present-then-simply-use-t

Answer (score 0):

Just run this `update` twice (or for as many times that a user can appear in the string:

```
update table2 
    set replace(definition_string, u.email, u.username)
    from users u
    where definition_string like '%' + u.email + '%';
```

This will be slow, but your table is smallish.

The issue is that only one update of an email takes effect on each iteration for each definition, so you have to do this multiple times.

Comment: Its not working. When I hardcode `u.email` and `u.username` with actual values then it works.

Comment: Its working now with some changes. Here is the final query - `update table2 
    set definition_string = replace(definition_string, u.email, u.username) 
    from users u where definition_string like '%' || u.email || '%'`

Comment: However one update for one email, two updates for two emails is the issue. It will be good if we do some regex kind to find the emails per record and then loop through it to do updates.

Comment: @MyGod . . . Multiple `update` statements.  Expensive, but perhaps the fastest way to do what you want on your data size.

Comment: but how will I know that row 1 needs how many update statements or row 2 needs how many update statements based on your given query so that I put loop accordingly ?

Comment: @MyGod . . . The `where` clause takes care of that.